# Neo4j - Object oriented Paradigm using Py2neo

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

I am learning Neo4j using py2neo. I wanted to know whether it has the capability to create objects in an Object Oriented Programming fashion like in neomodel.

Ex: Lets say, I have a class as follows:

```
Class Human{
         Age,
         height, 
         weight}
```

with age, height,weight as properties. Now, I wanted to create a node of type Human.

How can we do this through py2neo?
Any sample program would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Py2neo does not currently have an OGM. I have one partially developed that I will release with (probably) the next version but until then, no such functionality is available.